# Find index of previously matched cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filtering, data-mining

I haven't used python in a while so apologies if it's a stupid question!

I have a big panel dataset, that is multiple days for multiple ID's. Let's call this one `data1`

I also have `data2` which is a list of ID's that are in certain category.

I want to:

1. get the last day observed for each of those ID's from `data2` in `data1`
2. get the value in column `code`, in `data1`, that corresponds to that row

What I have so far is:

```
for i in data2.id.unique():
    last_day = data1[data1["ID"]==i]["datestamp"]
    code = data1[(data1["ID"==i])&(data1["datestamp"]==last_day)]["code"]
```

EDIT: I came up with a code to merge both, so now the new dataset looks like this:

```
ID | length | code | payments
01 | 230    | AAA  | 1
02 | 106    | BBB  | 4
03 | 128    | CCC  | 2
04 | 96     | AAA  | 3
05 | 205    | CCC  | 5
```

Where length is the number of days the client has been with the company.

Basically I want to say that when code is either AAA or CCC, a new column `new` takes the value of length, and when it is not AAA or CCC it takes 0.

I tried doing this:

```
df['new']=[df['length'] for x in df['code'] if x in ["AAA","CCC"]]
```

but that didn't work. I then tried it like this:

```
hello=[df['length'] for x in df['code'] if x in ["AAA","CCC"]]
```

And it worked, but it returned the full series `df["length"]` everytime the condition was met. I'm not sure how to make it so that if the condition is met, the value in `length` should be applied.

Comment: First, if you have a large dataset, loops should be the last thing to consider. What you could do is df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey'). more like a lookup. once you have your consolidated data(df3) you can then groupby.

Comment: With a merge and a groupby last ID I was able to get something like it. But now, I still need to know which ones have certain codes to then calculate how many days they have been in the company (I have a start date column and the datestamp which shows the last day, so I would calculate it with those). Is there a way to make it computationally not so expensive?

Comment: Can you provide an example input and output?

Comment: @Gage done :) explained a bit what I tried so far

Comment: Can you please share what the expected output will be for the newly merged dataset? It may just be a simple np.where clause to do the trick but more info is required to provide you the solution

Comment: Are you expecting column `new` to have the following: ID `01` will be `230`, ID `02` will be `0`, ID `03` will `128`, ID `04` will be `96` and ID `05` will be `205`? Or are you expecting the sum of ID `01` and `04` to be stored in `new`?

Comment: @JoeFerndz the first option you said. Each row with their corresponding length (or 0 otherwise)

Comment: @amestrian, see the solution I have shared. If that addresses your problem, then mark it as accepted solution and upvote. If you think we need to work on additional things, please provide your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to get a copy of `length` into `new` based on value in `code`.

IIUC, you want this.

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['ID','length','code']
d = [['01',230,'AAA'],
['02',106,'BBB'],
['03',128,'CCC'],
['04',96,'AAA'],
['05',205,'CCC']]

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
print (df)

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['length'] if x['code'] in ['AAA','CCC'] else 0, axis=1)
print (df)
```

with `axis=1`, it will process the logic row wise. And it will send the result to `df['new']`.

Original DataFrame:

```
   ID  length code
0  01     230  AAA
1  02     106  BBB
2  03     128  CCC
3  04      96  AAA
4  05     205  CCC
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
   ID  length code  new
0  01     230  AAA  230
1  02     106  BBB    0
2  03     128  CCC  128
3  04      96  AAA   96
4  05     205  CCC  205
```

Comment: I think it worked pretty well! I'll shout if I see any error but it looks like it's doing what it should. I do have a question though, is it even possible to do it just with a list comprehension? I don't know why I was sure it was possible, just want to know if I was mistaken

Comment: With pandas, when you reference df[col], you will get a pd.Series. So you will have more than one value as a result set. If you want to do a list comprehension, then you need to assign the value as a pd.Series(result).

Comment: Gotcha. Just realized I missed one tiny bit of the question initially. So it should either assign the `length` when code is in list `['AAA','CCC']` OR when `payment` (new column, see original post) => 3. Basically my question is, how to add an `OR` in the apply function?

Comment: You can give `df.apply(lambda x: x['length'] if (x['code'] in ['AAA','CCC']) or (x['payments'] >= 3) else 0, axis=1)`

Comment: This will assign ID = 2 with `BBB` as `106` as payments is `4`.